# TypeError: integer required occuring when sending packet

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, integer, packet

I am attempting to modify an open-source python script to accept strings instead of integers.
the following is the original python code:

```
def request(self, value):
   packet=''
   if self.domain:
     packet+=self.data[:2] + "\x81\x80"
     packet+=self.data[4:6] + self.data[4:6] + '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
     packet+=self.data[12:]
     packet+='\xc0\x0c'
     packet+='\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x3c\x00\x04'
     packet+=str.join('',map(lambda x: chr(int(x)), value.split('.')))
```

This works for integers and no errors appear.
I want to modify it to use strings instead of packets so i have tried to modify the `int` to `str` like follows:

```
def request(self, value):
   packet=''
   if self.domain:
     packet+=self.data[:2] + "\x81\x80"
     packet+=self.data[4:6] + self.data[4:6] + '\x00\x00\x00\x00'
     packet+=self.data[12:]
     packet+='\xc0\x0c'
     packet+='\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x3c\x00\x04'
     packet+=str.join('',map(lambda x: chr(str(x)), value.split('.')))
   return packet
```

However when i input a string as the value of the `value` parameter i receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 39, in <module>
    udps.sendto(p.request(value), addr)
  File "test.py", line 25, in request
    packet+=str.join('',map(lambda x: chr(str(x)), value.split('.')))
  File "test.py", line 25, in <lambda>
    packet+=str.join('',map(lambda x: chr(str(x)), value.split('.')))
TypeError: an integer is required
```

How can I modify line 25 to accept strings and not just integers? I still require the string `join` function.

Comment: What do you expect `chr(str(x))` to do? `chr` takes an integer and converts it to it's ascii character value. Of course it will fail when you pass a string. Can you give us an example of what `value` looks like?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is now working.

Answer (score 1):

`chr()` takes an integer and returns a string. You are passing it a string `chr(str(x))`. You either want `chr(x)` or `str(x)`.